# Cannot find module when using custom import paths with multiple tsconfigs

Tags: typescript

I've got a project with multiple `tsconfig.json` files. I'd like to shorten all imports, but for some reason shortened imports doesn't work in a specific scenario.

The project structure:

```
foo/
|  main.ts
|  tsconfig.json
projects/
|  bar/
|    index.ts
tsconfig.json
```

Whenever I want to compile `foo/main.ts` I get the following error: `Cannot find module @bar/shared`.

Some details:

The `projects/bar/index.ts` file simply exports a plain class: `export class Foo {}`

The `foo/main.ts` tries to import the `Foo` class:

```
import {Foo} from '@bar/shared';
```

Last but not least the `tsconfig.json` within `foo`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "outDir": "../dist/foo"
  }
}
```

And the root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@bar/shared": ["projects/bar"]
    }
  }
}
```

My IDE is completely satisfied - but I'm unable to compile.

Comment: Where is `./src` in your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

In your `foo/tsconfig.json` file, delete the `baseUrl` entry, because it is incorrectly overriding the `baseUrl` entry in the root `tsconfig.json` file.

#### Details

The `baseUrl` value is the base directory from which to resolve both non-relative module names and `paths` mapping entries. As a result, when resolving the `@bar/shared` mapping entry, the module resolution strategy searched relative to the `baseUrl` of `./src`. Further, since `./src` is a relative path, its full path is based on the location of its `/foo/tsconfig.json` file. Thus, the path mapping entry resolved to `./foo/src/projects/bar/`.

All these details and more are available in [the module resolution docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

#### `--traceResolution`

A great tool for troubleshooting these errors is to build with the `--traceResolution` option. For your project set up, building with it from the `foo/` directory includes this output:

> Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location `'C:/dev/temp/foo/src/projects/bar'`, target file type 'TypeScript'.

#### Runtime

TypeScript path mapping allows path mappings but does not re-write those paths. The runtime (in your case `node`) must know how to find `@bar/shared`. You will need to configure your runtime with the path mappings too. Here is a `node` package that lets you do that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Comment: I've updated my `tsconfig.json` files - I'm now able to compile, but as soon as I try to run the compiled code via `node dist/foo/main.js` I get the same error (`Cannot find module @bar/shared`)

Comment: @nehalist You need to configure the path mappings for your runtime too. I added some details to the answer.